# What technology can i use to run a method on a browser(client side) every time a user uploads a picture?

Tags: browser, applet, browser-extension, applet-servlet

I have a custom function/method that needs to run on the browser (client side) every time the user uploads a picture to a web-server. This method modifies the image being uploaded and sends it to the server.

Currently the method is written in java so I thought of using an applet on the browser which could run this method and then send the modified picture to a servlet residing on the server, but the applet has certain disk read/write restrictions. I am aware of policies that can be used to grant these permissions to the applet but they need the users consent every time.

Also I want to avoid the applet .class file to be downloaded every time this page is viewed. So

1. Is there a cleaner approach to all this?
2. Are there any other technologies that can help me run this method on the browser ? (its ok if i have to rewrite the function in a different language)
3. Is writing a custom browser extension a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the JS using will be much better for this task.

One of JS image processing [JS-library](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/)
, just for example.

[How to invoke a servlet from JS example](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=39154)

Writing a browser extension is a really wrong way.